List to DataFrame with row and column headers
I need to convert a list (including headers) to a Dataframe.
If I do it directly using pl.DataFrame(list), the headers are created and everything is kept as a string. Moreover, the table is transposed, such that the first element in the list becomes the first column in the dataframe.
Input list.
[
    ['Earnings estimate', 'Current qtr. (Jun 2024)', 'Next qtr. (Sep 2024)', 'Current year (2024)', 'Next year (2025)'],
    ['No. of analysts', '13', '11', '26', '26'],
    ['Avg. Estimate', '1.52', '1.62', '6.27', '7.23'],
    ['Low estimate', '1.36', '1.3', '5.02', '5.88'],
    ['High estimate', '1.61', '1.74', '6.66', '8.56'],
    ['Year ago EPS', '1.76', '1.36', '5.74', '6.27'],
]

Expected output.


You can explicitly define the orient= to prevent transposition:
pl.DataFrame(data[1:], orient="row", schema=data[0])

shape: (5, 5)
┌───────────────────┬─────────────────────────┬──────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬──────────────────┐
│ Earnings estimate ┆ Current qtr. (Jun 2024) ┆ Next qtr. (Sep 2024) ┆ Current year (2024) ┆ Next year (2025) │
│ ---               ┆ ---                     ┆ ---                  ┆ ---                 ┆ ---              │
│ str               ┆ str                     ┆ str                  ┆ str                 ┆ str              │
╞═══════════════════╪═════════════════════════╪══════════════════════╪═════════════════════╪══════════════════╡
│ No. of analysts   ┆ 13                      ┆ 11                   ┆ 26                  ┆ 26               │
│ Avg. Estimate     ┆ 1.52                    ┆ 1.62                 ┆ 6.27                ┆ 7.23             │
│ Low estimate      ┆ 1.36                    ┆ 1.3                  ┆ 5.02                ┆ 5.88             │
│ High estimate     ┆ 1.61                    ┆ 1.74                 ┆ 6.66                ┆ 8.56             │
│ Year ago EPS      ┆ 1.76                    ┆ 1.36                 ┆ 5.74                ┆ 6.27             │
└───────────────────┴─────────────────────────┴──────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴──────────────────┘


For completeness, Polars also has a constructor for record-like data: polars.from_records that you can use here as well.
import polars as pl

data = [
    ['Earnings estimate',  'Current qtr.',  'Next qtr.'],
    ['No. of analysts',    '13',            '11',      ],
    ['Avg. Estimate',      '1.52',          '1.62',    ],
    ['Low estimate',       '1.36',          '1.3',     ],
    ['High estimate',      '1.61',          '1.74',    ],
    ['Year ago EPS',       '1.76',          '1.36',    ],
]

df = pl.from_records(data[1:], schema=data[0])
print(df)
# shape: (5, 3)
# ┌───────────────────┬──────────────┬───────────┐
# │ Earnings estimate ┆ Current qtr. ┆ Next qtr. │
# │ ---               ┆ ---          ┆ ---       │
# │ str               ┆ str          ┆ str       │
# ╞═══════════════════╪══════════════╪═══════════╡
# │ No. of analysts   ┆ 13           ┆ 11        │
# │ Avg. Estimate     ┆ 1.52         ┆ 1.62      │
# │ Low estimate      ┆ 1.36         ┆ 1.3       │
# │ High estimate     ┆ 1.61         ┆ 1.74      │
# │ Year ago EPS      ┆ 1.76         ┆ 1.36      │
# └───────────────────┴──────────────┴───────────┘


DataFrame constructor has a parameter orient:

orient : {‘col’, ‘row’}, default None
Whether to interpret
two-dimensional data as columns or as rows. If None, the orientation
is inferred by matching the columns and data dimensions. If this does
not yield conclusive results, column orientation is used.

So in your case, col orientation is used, but you can manually set it to row:
pl.DataFrame(data[1:], schema=data[0], orient="row")

shape: (5, 5)
┌───────────────────┬─────────────────────────┬──────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬──────────────────┐
│ Earnings estimate ┆ Current qtr. (Jun 2024) ┆ Next qtr. (Sep 2024) ┆ Current year (2024) ┆ Next year (2025) │
│ ---               ┆ ---                     ┆ ---                  ┆ ---                 ┆ ---              │
│ str               ┆ str                     ┆ str                  ┆ str                 ┆ str              │
╞═══════════════════╪═════════════════════════╪══════════════════════╪═════════════════════╪══════════════════╡
│ No. of analysts   ┆ 13                      ┆ 11                   ┆ 26                  ┆ 26               │
│ Avg. Estimate     ┆ 1.52                    ┆ 1.62                 ┆ 6.27                ┆ 7.23             │
│ Low estimate      ┆ 1.36                    ┆ 1.3                  ┆ 5.02                ┆ 5.88             │
│ High estimate     ┆ 1.61                    ┆ 1.74                 ┆ 6.66                ┆ 8.56             │
│ Year ago EPS      ┆ 1.76                    ┆ 1.36                 ┆ 5.74                ┆ 6.27             │
└───────────────────┴─────────────────────────┴──────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴──────────────────┘


